# basic question c++, dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a  class

```
class person
{
char* name;
public:
void setname(const char*);
};
void person::setname(const char* p)
{
name=new char[strlen(p)];
strcpy(name,p);
name[strlen(p)]='\0';
}
```

My question is about the line 
name=new char[strlen(p)];
suppose the p pointer is pointing to string i.e “zia” , now strlen(p) will return 3 it means we have an array of 4 characters i.e char[3] now I copy the string into the name and at the 4th location , I put the null character , what is wrong with this?????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say:

> we have an array of 4 characters i.e
>   char[3]

Surprisingly enough, char[3] is an array of THREE characters, not FOUR!

Comment: I am so sorry, I don't know what the hell I was thinking!

My apologies, I've been fasting and am at the end of a long day. :S

Answer (score 3):

You MUST allocate one more char for zero terminator:

```
name = new char[strlen(p) + 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems are

1. You never `delete[] name;`, thus every time the user calls `setname()`, you leak an array.
2. To accomodate the extra `'\0'` you need to allocate for `strlen(p)+1` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate one more memory position for the \0 character otherwise when you do this `name[strlen(p)]='\0';` you get a Segmentation Fault. Basically do `new char[strlen(p) + 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should allocate strlen(p)+1 characters:

```
name = new char[strlen(p)+1];
```

Answer (score 2):

The point where you're going wrong is here:

> now strlen(p) will return 3 it means we have an array of 4 characters i.e char[3]

An array of 4 characters is a `char[4]`; if you allocate dynamically, you will have to pass 4 to `operator new` or, in general:

```
name=new char[strlen(p)+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void person::setname(const char* p)
{

name=new char[strlen(p) + 1]; // make a room to have null character 
strcpy(name,p);
name[strlen(p)]='\0';

}
```

array index starts from 0 so max index for array of size = 5 is arr[4].

Comment: strcpy puts the 0 terminator in - no need to do it again

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have mentioned a cure for the immediate problem you've encountered. In doing so, they've almost done you a disservice though. Unless you have a *really* good reason to do otherwise, what you should probably do is define the name as and `std::string`, and use its assignment operator to handle the job correctly.

If you do have a spectacularly good reason to avoid using `std::string`, then you should design a string class of your own, and use it instead. At least in my opinion, writing code the way you have, with dynamic allocations and `strcpy`s all over the place is just a poor idea. Even at very best, it's difficult to read, prone to lots of silly off-by-one errors, and essentially impossible to make anywhere close to exception safe.